# Search dates between ranges of periods and count occurrences

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
> data have;
> input ID :$20. Start :date9. End :date9.;
> format start end ddmmyy9.;
> cards;
> 0001 01JAN2015 30JUN2015 
> 0001 01JUL2015 01FEB2016 
> 0001 02FEB2016 11DEC2016 
> 0001 12DEC2016 06FEB2017 
> 0001 07FEB2017 31DEC2017 
> 0002 01JAN2016 31DEC2017 
> 0002 01JAN2018 01MAR2018
> 0002 01APR2018 31NOV2018
> ......................
> ;
> ```

and a list of dates:

```
data dates;            
input dates :$20.;              
format dates ddmmyy9.;    
cards; 
01JAN2015 
31DEC2015 
01JAN2016 
31DEC2016 
01JAN2017 
31DEC2017 
01JAN2018 
31DEC2018 
;
```

Is there a way to know if, for each ID, each date is in the range? For example:  the ID 0001 contains all dates except 01JAN2018 and 31DEC2018.
Moreover, for each year I need to count how many IDs start at 01/01 and end at 31/12 so they appear for the entire year. For example, ID 0002 will not be counted for 2018 because it ends before 31/12. Desired output:

> ```
> ID       01JAN2015  31DEC2015  01JAN2016 31DEC2016 01JAN2017  31DEC2017  01JAN2018   31DEC2018
> 0001        yes        yes         yes       yes       yes      yes         no         no       
> 0002         no         no         yes       yes       yes      yes         yes        no
> ```

Final table:

> ```
>  Year       Count      
>  2015         1         
>  2016         2
>  2017         2       
>  2018         0
> ```

To match the dates in the range I tried:

> ```
>    proc sql;
>    create table want as;
>    select dates as t1;
>    join have as t2;       
>    t2.dates between t1.start and t1.end
>    order by 1,2;        
>    quit;
> ```

Unfortunately I lose the ID correspondence.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need both the data for each ID and the final table?

Comment: It would be preferable to have both for subsequent analysis, but only if it is not so hard to generate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first output can be achieved using `proc sql` followed by `proc transpose` and then a `data` step. 
*(The variables are created in a different order than in your desired output - hopefully that is not a problem for you.)*

The second can be done with a `data` step followed by `proc summary`.

*NB - I changed the invalid date 31NOV2018 to 30NOV2018 before running my code.*

## Output 1

```
* First, join the HAVE and DATES data sets to check which dates fall within a range;
proc sql;
    create table want1 as
        select h.ID, d.dates format=date9., 'yes' as flag
            from dates d left join have h on (d.dates between h.start and h.end)
            order by ID, dates      
            ;
run;

* transpose this to the wider format required. Cells where there is no match will be blank;
proc transpose data=want1 out=want1 (where=(ID ne '') drop=_name_); 
    by ID;
    id dates;
    var flag;
run;

* Now populate the blank cells with "no";
data want1;
    set want1;
    array datevars (*) _all_;
    do i = 1 to dim(datevars);
        if datevars(i) = '' then datevars(i)='no';
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

## Output 2

```
* This assumes the data are in order by ID, start and end - if not then sort the data before this step;
* First read throught the HAVE data set and set count = 1 for each year that is fully covered by each ID;
data want2;
    set have;
    by ID;
    retain first last count; * FIRST and LAST are the earliest START and latest END respectively for each ID;
    if first.ID then do;
        first=start;
        count=0;
    end;
    if last.ID then do;
        last=end;
        do yr=year(first) to year(last); * for each ID we want to cycle through all the years covered;
            if first <= mdy(1,1,yr) and last >= mdy(12,31,yr) then count = 1; * sets count=1 if the year is fully contained within the range;
            output; 
            count=0;    
        end;            
    end;
    drop start end first last;
    format first last date9.;
run;

* The step above produces a row for each combination of year * ID, we just want totals by year which is done by PROC SUMMARY;
proc summary data=want2 nway;
    class yr;
    var count;
    output out=want2 (drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=;
run;
```